# How to add precondition for unique index?

Tags: mysql, liquibase

What I want to do is;If there is an index(non-unique) named "message_id" then drop it and create an unique index with same name.

Below code doesn't checks for uniqueness. Is there a way to do this?

By the way I can write an "sqlcheck" statement but I need to find a way to get "message_id" index's uniqueness with mysql query.

```
<changeSet author="mark" id="201589895236">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <indexExists schemaName="${database.name}" indexName="message_id"/>            
    </preConditions>
    <comment>comment for message_id index</comment>        
    <createIndex indexName="message_id" tableName="user_info" unique="true">
        <column name="message_id"/>
        <column name="message_prefix"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible, nothing related to unique is here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/precondition/core/IndexExistsPrecondition.java
So you should use SQL check or implement your own custom precondition.